# What does it mean when MAE improved while RMSE worsened?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, rms, mae, tweedie-distribution

I am comparing two models:
One is a black box that I cannot understand, the other is a GLM. 
[image]

How can I describe why the differences are like this? Is the GLM performing worse than the blackbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your model after improvement from blackbox has reduced the number of large errors according to RMSE, but as the MAE suggests, the total error has increased.

See [MAE and RMSE — Which Metric is Better?](https://medium.com/human-in-a-machine-world/mae-and-rmse-which-metric-is-better-e60ac3bde13d)

Here are some quotes from that page:

> Taking the square root of the average squared errors has some
>   interesting implications for RMSE. Since the errors are squared before
>   they are averaged, the RMSE gives a relatively high weight to large
>   errors. This means the RMSE should be more useful when large errors
>   are particularly undesirable.